# Xamarin - cut off text in frame with three dots

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a frame with two texts, done with a grid of two rows:

[image]

This way, everything looks fine. But when the second text is longer than the frame, this row becomes empty:

[image]

Now what I need is the option that the text continues to almost the end of the frame and is then cut-off with three points like this:

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/label#truncation-and-wrapping

Comment: Just add `LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"` to Label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `LineBreakMode` attribute as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/label#truncation-and-wrapping)

```
<Label Text="Text 1&#x0a;This is a very long text which does not fit."
   LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
   MaxLines="2" />
```